# How to obtain the same result with "some_number.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big').decode()" (Python) in C#?

Tags: c#, python

I'm trying to do this:

```
System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)code))
```

But it's converting it to 4 bytes and I want only 1 byte...

Comment: How about `BitConverter.GetBytes(value).First();`?

Comment: What is `code`? Is it a variable of type `byte`? If so, what does this byte represent? Is it a character code? If it is a character code, what code-page/encoding is this character code based on? So many questions, so much unclear about what the input data is and what the desired result data is...

Comment: Anyway, assuming that `code` is of type `byte`, just create a `code` byte array with this byte as its single element. Then pass this single-element byte array directly to `GetString(...)`. No need screwing around with BitConverter and picking bytes from a 32-bit value...